# BitTorrent client: trouble downloading last few blocks from peers

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, bittorrent, python-asyncio

The BitTorrent client I'm working on is almost working except it couldnt get the last few blocks from peers even though the requests have been sent. I get no data from peers except for `keep-alive` messages and peers would close their connection after sending a few `keep-alive`.

I know there is a end game mode, where there's a tendency for the last few blocks to trickle in slowly. But in my case, all peers would stop sending any data when there are a few blocks left and close their connection one by one.

What could be the problem that is causing this?

```
2016-07-19 15:05:27,131 - main.torrent_client - INFO - we have piece 69
2016-07-19 15:05:27,131 - main.torrent_client - INFO - downloaded: 71, total: 72
2016-07-19 15:05:27,132 - main.torrent_client - INFO - peer queue {70, 71}
2016-07-19 15:05:27,132 - main.torrent_client - INFO - 2 blocks left to request from 198.251.56.71
2016-07-19 15:05:27,132 - main.torrent_client - INFO - pop a block from piece 70
2016-07-19 15:05:27,132 - main.torrent_client - INFO - peer queue {71}
2016-07-19 15:05:27,132 - main.torrent_client - INFO - 1 blocks left to request from 198.251.56.71
2016-07-19 15:05:27,133 - main.torrent_client - INFO - pop a block from piece 71    
2016-07-19 15:05:30,138 - main.torrent_client - INFO - requested {'index': 71, 'begin_offset': 0, 'request_length': 16384} from 198.251.56.71

2016-07-19 15:05:27,133 - main.pieces - INFO - Done requesting all the pieces!!!!!!!!!

2016-07-19 15:06:18,066 - main.torrent_client - INFO - just sent keep alive message to {'port': 57430, 'host': '198.251.56.71'}
2016-07-19 15:06:18,066 - main.torrent_client - INFO - just sent keep alive message to {'port': 29063, 'host': '38.76.93.8'}

2016-07-19 15:07:15,856 - main.torrent_client - DEBUG - Peer {'port': 29063, 'host': '38.76.93.8'} sent KEEP ALIVE message
2016-07-19 15:07:48,065 - main.torrent_client - INFO - just sent keep alive message to {'port': 57430, 'host': '198.251.56.71'}
2016-07-19 15:07:48,065 - main.torrent_client - INFO - just sent keep alive message to {'port': 29063, 'host': '38.76.93.8'}

2016-07-19 15:09:16,796 - main.torrent_client - DEBUG - Peer {'port': 29063, 'host': '38.76.93.8'} sent KEEP ALIVE message
2016-07-19 15:09:18,066 - main.torrent_client - INFO - just sent keep alive message to {'port': 57430, 'host': '198.251.56.71'}  
2016-07-19 15:10:48,070 - main.torrent_client - INFO - just sent keep alive message to {'port': 29063, 'host': '38.76.93.8'}
2016-07-19 15:11:17,785 - main.torrent_client - DEBUG - Peer {'port': 29063, 'host': '38.76.93.8'} sent KEEP ALIVE message

2016-07-19 15:13:48,073 - main.torrent_client - DEBUG - connection closed by {'port': 57430, 'host': '198.251.56.71'}
```

Comment: Maybe you send **Uninterested** to all peers a bit too early after you have sent the last request?!

Comment: @Encombe I'm not sending Uninterested to any peer. Interesting, if i start requesting from last block instead of the first block, I also get no response from the peers. The program would get stuck from very beginning.

Comment: OK, then maybe the last request is to large. Remember that the last chunk in the last piece is smaller than 16 KB in almost all torrents. This is if you do sequential downloading. (Which is a bad thing to do, **Rarest first** is essential for for the health of the swarm.)

Comment: @Encombe You are absolutely right. I forgot to calculate the last piece length which made last block incorrect. Thank you! I would gladly to choose your answer as the right answer if you would like to repost it as an answer.